# FFmpeg - Possible to overlay video side-by-side and "pass through"?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two video files with unknown durations.  I need to have them play back side-by-side.  I also need them to end at the duration of the longest clip

My filtergraph currently looks like:

-filter_complex "[0:v]pad=x=1408:y=480[p];[p][1:v]overlay=x=704:y=0[out]" ......

Currently, the files play back side-by-side correctly, but when one stream ends, it holds the last frame.  I would prefer if it simply "turned off" and showed the black data from the pad.

I tried playing with the eof_action=pass parameter, but this only works if my "main input" is the file with the longest duration.  Since I don't know which file is longest, my problem is a bit challenging.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are they the same resolution?

Comment: In the example above - yes ... But They may not always be the same resolution.  Is there a reason why that might matter to your answer?  I could always pad each file to be the same resolution if needed - but that would add some extra steps that I'd like to avoid if possible